# How Do I Display Youtube site/video within Webview?

Tags: android, webview, youtube

I am noob to android and i want to navigate youtube.com and show video from the site inside of a webview.  Currenty, when i try to do this, the device's browser appears and makes me navigate the site using the device browser.  If the webview, is not capable of this type of functionality, how do i place the device's default browser in my layout as i would a webview so that the site can be viewed within the application.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

My code so far:

```
    huffingtonpost = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    huffingtonpost.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    huffingtonpost.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    huffingtonpost.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    try{
    huffingtonpost.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com/KitcoNews");
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Have you read about handling page navigation to prevent the OS from overriding the url and opening the default browser? See the following...http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#HandlingNavigation

Comment: Cool.  this allows me to navigate, but won't allow me to play video  now.

Comment: Hmmm, I've never done anything with YouTube or any other web site videos. The docs for `WebView` mention cookies and also HTML5 inline video support - does that help? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Handling Page Navigation](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#HandlingNavigation) which explains how to prevent Android from opening the default/stock browser. Quote below...

> When the user clicks a link from a web page in your WebView, the default behavior is for Android to launch an application that handles URLs. Usually, the default web browser opens and loads the destination URL. However, you can override this behavior for your WebView, so links open within your WebView.